# issue with eclipse after checking out project from svn

Tags: svn, eclipse

After checking out a project from SVN, I am getting the following prompt in eclipse any time I try to change anything in the code:

```
The compilation unit is not in the build path of the project
```

There is no Java build path option when I right click on the project.
Any ideas on how to troubleshoot or fix the issue will be greatly appreciated.

**Note:**
I tried changing the project file manually but now my project files are being displayed in separate directories inside the trunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply checked out the project using eclipse (Create new project using wizard) option and this time, it worked without any issues.  I might not have chosen the create new project using the wizard option last time I checked out the project using svn.